# Convert docx to PDF in raised exception

Tags: c#, pdf

I have console application for converting word document into pdf.

Here am using using "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word" dll version is 14.0.

Here is a sample code

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application appWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
wordDocument = appWord.Documents.Open(@"c:\temp\DocToPDF.docx");
wordDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat(@"c:\temp\DocTo.pdf", WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF);
```

This code raised exception

> "COM Exception was unhandled" "The export failed because this feature
>   is not installed."

Please help me to converting docx to PDF.

Comment: This exception can be raised when world does not have the correct add ins necessary to convert a doc to a pdf. What version of MS word are you using?

Comment: I am using Office 2007

Comment: Please have a look at this page. Installing the pdf exporting addin may solve the issue.http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/67fa9a8a-3326-47d2-94cd-544e94b2c503/converting-word-to-pdf-export-failed-because-this-feature-is-not-installed?forum=vblanguage

Comment: Yes u suggest me to install 2007 addin to solve this issue but if on my client side there is office 2003 or else 2010 what about this?will it be solve ??????

Comment: They will also need to have the right addin installed on their system. Unfortunately this is how the office api's work.

Comment: So, this is not a proper solution.Can you please suggest or send me the c# code to convert Doc or docx file to PDF file.

Comment: I'm afraid it is the only solution using Microsoft API's, you simple HAVE to have the right software installed. You may be able to find a third party tool to do it, but i have not with a quick google search.